# java - withdraw from bank account using a method

Tags: java

Building a basic bank account with Java using methods. I am creating a new method to withdraw from the bank account. This is the code that I came up with right now, but on netbeans it shows that there are errors.

I created a new method called **withDrawal**. This code below is for the withdrawing from account and to not let the balance in the account go below zero!

```
private static void withDrawal() 
    {

        int accountIndex = findAccount();
        int verifyPin = checkPin (!=0);
            if(accountIndex != -1)
            if(verifyPin !=-2)

            {        
            accounts[accountIndex].withDrawal();
            accounts[verifyPin].checkPin();
            int withDra = input.nextInt();


            }
            else 
            {
                System.out.println("Account does not exist!");
                System.out.printf("Enter amount you want to withdraw: ");

            }
    }
```

**Java file**

```
package grossmontbank;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class GrossmontBank 
{
    //class variables (global - accessible throughout this class)

    //scanner object to be used throughout
    private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //array of blank accounts
    private static final int MAX_ACCOUNTS = 50;
    private static Account[] accounts = new Account[MAX_ACCOUNTS];

    //total accounts created
    private static int totalAccounts = 0;

    //main class mimics a bank teller 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        char choice;

        //loop until 'Q' is entered
        do
        {
            choice = getChoice(); //getChoice() will only return with a C, B, W, D or Q
            if(choice != 'Q')
            {
                switch(choice)
                {
                    case 'C':   createAccount();
                                break;

                    case 'B':   checkBalance();
                                break;

                    case 'W':   
                                break;

                    case 'D':   
                                break;
                }                
            }            
        }while(choice != 'Q');

        closeBank(); //outputs all account holders and 'closes' the bank

    }

    /*method checkBalance  calls method findAccount()
    *                      if account exists, calls Account method checkBalance()
    */
    private static void checkBalance()
    {
        int accountIndex = findAccount();        
        //findAccount() returns index of account if found, -1 if not found
        if(accountIndex != -1)
        {
            accounts[accountIndex].checkBalance();
        }
        else
        {
             System.out.println("Account does not exist");
        }
    }

    /*method checkIfExists  determines if account holder already exists
    *                      returns true if account holder exists, false otherwise
    */   
    private static boolean checkIfExists(String firstName, String lastName)
    {
        //loops through account array to see if account name already exists
        for(int i = 0; i < totalAccounts;i++)
        {
            //compares the names, ignoring upper/lower
            if(accounts[i].getFirstName().equalsIgnoreCase(firstName) 
                    && accounts[i].getLastName().equalsIgnoreCase(lastName))
            {
                System.out.println("Account holder already exists.  Please verify and re-enter. ");
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /*method closeBank  prints out closing statement
    *                   prints out list of all account holders
    */
    private static void closeBank()
    {
        System.out.println("Closing the follow accounts:");

        for(int i = 0; i < totalAccounts;i++)
        {
            //printing an account object invokes the Account class method toString()
            //prints first and last name only
            System.out.printf("    %s%n",accounts[i]); 
        }        
        System.out.println("Grossmont Bank is officially closed.");        
    }

     /*method createAccount creates a single bank account
    *                      checks to ensure account holder does not already exist
    *                      returns Account object
    */
    private static void createAccount()
    {
        String first, last, initial;
        boolean exists = false;

        //only create a new account if MAX_ACCOUNTS has not been reached
        if(totalAccounts < MAX_ACCOUNTS )
        {
            //loop until a new account name has been entered
            do
            {
                System.out.print("Enter your first name: ");
                first = input.next();
                System.out.print("Enter your last name: ");
                last = input.next();
                exists = checkIfExists(first,last);
            }while(exists == true);

            System.out.print("Will you be making an initial deposit? Enter Yes or No: ");
            initial = input.next();

            //if no initial deposit, call 2 parameter constructor, otherwise call 3 param one
            if(initial.equals("No"))
            {
                accounts[totalAccounts] = new Account(first,last);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print("Enter initial deposit amount: ");
                accounts[totalAccounts] = new Account(first,last, input.nextDouble());
            }

            //increment totalAccounts created (used throughout program)
            totalAccounts++;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Maximum number of accounts has been reached. ");
        }
    }

    /*method findAccount   asks for first and last name
    *                      searchs for account holder in array
    *                      if exists, returns array index of this account
    *                      if doesn't exist, returns '-1'
    *                      called from checkBalance()
    */
    private static int findAccount()
    {
        String first, last;

        System.out.print("Enter first name: ");
        first = input.next();
        System.out.print("Enter last name: ");
        last = input.next();

        //loops through account array
        for(int i = 0; i < totalAccounts;i++)
        {
            //compares the names, ignoring upper/lower
            if(accounts[i].getFirstName().equalsIgnoreCase(first) 
                    && accounts[i].getLastName().equalsIgnoreCase(last))
            {
                return i; //returns the index of the account
            }
        }
        return -1; //if account not found

    }


     /* method getChoice()   outputs options 
    *                       inputs choice from user and validates
    *                       returns choice char
    */                      
    private static char getChoice()
    {
        char choice;

        //output menu options
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Welcome to Grossmont Bank.  Choose from the following options: ");
        System.out.println("    C - create new account");
        System.out.println("    B - check your balance");
        System.out.println("    D - deposit");
        System.out.println("    W - withdrawal");
        System.out.println("    Q - quit");

        //loop until a valid input is entered
        do
        {
            System.out.print("Enter choice: ");
            choice = input.next().charAt(0);
            //if choice is one of the options, return it.  Otherwise keep looping
            if(choice == 'C' || choice == 'B' || choice == 'D' || choice == 'W' || choice == 'Q')
                return choice;
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid choice.  Ensure a capital letter. Please re-enter.");
                choice = '?';
            }
        }while(choice == '?');

        return choice;  //will never get here, but required to have a return statement to compile   
    }


    private static void withDrawal() 
    {

        int accountIndex = findAccount();
        int verifyPin = checkPin (!=0);
            if(accountIndex != -1)
            if(verifyPin !=-2)

            {        
            accounts[accountIndex].withDrawal();
            accounts[verifyPin].checkPin();
            int withDra = input.nextInt();


            }
            else 
            {
                System.out.println("Account does not exist!");
                System.out.printf("Enter amount you want to withdraw: ");

            }
    }


}
```

Comment: what error are you getting? Can you share it here?

Comment: You didn't need if after switch case because, you already have an exit expression (while(choice != 'Q'))

Comment: I don't see any code here showing that you have tried to accomplish what you say you are... There no code that checks the amount of money in the account, nor is there code that would check the amount input to be withdrawn against the amount of money in the account.  This is not a code writing service.  Also, next time make sure your code compiles this: `int verifyPin = checkPin (!=0)` will not compile...